# Cannot find symbol in java asking to create a class

Tags: java

I am having a class defined as follows:

```
public class Myclass { 
   public int myvariable = 100;

   if( myvariable > 0) {

   }
}
```

Why I am getting an error in front of `if condition` stating that `cannot find symbol , symbol : class myvariable , location : class Myclass  <identifier> expected`

I am just comparing the value of integer variable with 0 here. Based on the error, I would need to create a class. Please let me know what's wrong here.

Comment: That `if` statement belongs inside a method.

Comment: What method is this `if` statement in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write statement inside executable block (method, static initializer, constructor etc)